# No WiFI, Dell XPS 15 9575

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

Put simply WiFi isn't working on the laptop. The network card which is of the ath10k variety has been bad in the past, but now it is simply not working. The laptop is running linux mint 19.1. I have tried installing new drivers to /lib/firmware/[ath10k](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware), I have tried updating my kernel to 4.19, I have tried fixing my kernel update, I have tried creating a driver [configuration file](https://pastebin.com/4ZcjmSpi) and I have tried turning off wifi powersave in NetworkManager and TLP. Here's the output to some diagnostic commands.

inxi -Fxxxz
https://pastebin.com/hsc93MW7

lspci | grep ath
`no output`

sudo lshw -C network
`no output`

dmesg | grep ath

`[   63.835354] ath10k_core: unknown parameter 'nohwcrypt' ignored
[   63.836722] ath10k_pci: unknown parameter 'nohwcrypt' ignored
[   63.836723] ath10k_pci: unknown parameter 'skip_otp' ignored`

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
`no output`

sudo modprobe ath10k_pci `no output`

Comment: Your `inxi` only shows a `Ralink RT5370 Wireless Adapter type: USB driver: rt2800usb`. Is this a replacement adapter and the Atheros card is disabled in BIOS?

Comment: I run mint on one of my Dell laptops also with that ath (mini card). Mine showed up w/o issue. What happens if you press the FN key and the Wireless key on your keyboard. Does the card *suddenly* show up?

Comment: The Ralink is simply a replacement adapter. I just tried to turn the atheros card off and then back on in BIOS. This did not work. I also tried the wireless key. I know for sure that the integrated wireless card  (atheros) is still working somewhat because bluetooth is showing up and it is a combined bluetooth and wireless card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me. I deleted /lib/firmware/ath10k. I then ran these two commands. The first fixes firmware and gets the latest version, the second turns off some wifi powersaving features. I did this on kernel 4.19.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Comment: How did you have working internet after deleting your wi-fi card's firmware?

Comment: was using a second USB wifi card to still access the internet